# python tkinter resize background image according to window size

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

The background image is not adjusting automatically to the window size in python using tkinter

**Following is the code snippet**

```
        self.background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="background.png")
        self.background_label = tk.Label(self.master, image=self.background_image)
        self.background_label.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
```

The image should be in background of the behind all the GUI components.

The code is actually a part of a python GUI but the image is not resizing automatically according to the window size previously i tried this but it was to add a static image but in need the image to fit automatically to the window size

**This is the kinda the complete code**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MongoDBGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("MongoDB Cloud Search and Display")
        self.master.geometry("1000x400")

        self.background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="background.png")
        self.background_label = tk.Label(self.master, image=self.background_image)
        self.background_label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        
        self.label = tk.Label(self.master, text="Enter search criteria:")
        self.label.pack()
        
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.master)
        self.entry.pack()
        
        self.search_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Search", command=self.search)
        self.search_button.pack()
        
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.master)
        self.tree.pack()
        self.tree["columns"] = ("transcript", "audio_file", "audio")
        self.tree.column("transcript", width=400, anchor="center")
        self.tree.column("audio_file", width=150, anchor="center")
        self.tree.column("audio", width=50, anchor="center")
        self.tree.heading("transcript", text="Transcript")
        self.tree.heading("audio_file", text="Audio File Number")
        self.tree.heading("audio", text="Audio")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an not so easy task. If you want to have a resizable image then you need to use the PIL package. Additionally a further method is needed to rezise the image dynamically. Ofcourse if the window size always stays the same the solution could be implemented like :

```
self.image = self.img_copy.resize((new_width, new_height))
#resize is included in the PIL.Image module
```

To dynamically resize the background Picture the code could look like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from scipy import misc,datasets
from PIL import Image, ImageTk



class MongoDBGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("MongoDB Cloud Search and Display")
        self.master.geometry("1000x400")

        self.image = Image.open("background.png")
        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.img_copy = self.image.copy()
        self.background_label = tk.Label(self.master, image=self.background_image)
        self.background_label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        self.label = tk.Label(self.master, text="Enter search criteria:")
        self.label.pack()

        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.master)
        self.entry.pack()

        self.search_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Search", command=self.search)
        self.search_button.pack()

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.master)
        self.tree.pack()
        self.tree["columns"] = ("transcript", "audio_file", "audio")
        self.tree.column("transcript", width=400, anchor="center")
        self.tree.column("audio_file", width=150, anchor="center")
        self.tree.column("audio", width=50, anchor="center")
        self.tree.heading("transcript", text="Transcript")
        self.tree.heading("audio_file", text="Audio File Number")
        self.tree.heading("audio", text="Audio")
        self.background_label.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)

    def _resize_image(self,event):

        new_width = event.width
        new_height = event.height

        self.image = self.img_copy.resize((new_width, new_height))

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.background_label.configure(image =  self.background_image)


master=tk.Tk()
test=MongoDBGUI(master)
master.mainloop()
```